# Find nth central moment for exponential distribution

Tags: exponential-distribution, moments, method-of-moments

I am trying to figure out what the nth **central** moment is for the exponential distribution.
Here is the formula for the nth moment:

$$
\mathop{\mathbb{E}}{[x^n]} =\dfrac{n!}{\lambda^n}
$$

**My question**: what is the continuous formula for the exponential distribution for the nth *central* moment?

[image]

Comment: This seems like a [tag:self-study] question. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? The wikipedia page for central moments seems to answer this question completely: just use the definition & binomial theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_moment What, specifically, is giving you trouble?

Comment: @Sycorax is there a place in that wiki article that provides the answer for the exponential distribution? A derivation would be nice too.

Comment: Its straight substitution into the formula there. For a derivation just use the straight binomial expansion of $(a+b)^n$ with $a=X$ and $ b=-\mu$ and use the same substitution to get the exponential result

Comment: @Glen_b that sounds great Glen can you add a full answer to OP with the answer button?

Comment: Isn't this straightforward by calculating the integral $E(X^n) = \int_0^\infty x^n \lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx$?

Comment: @Zhanxiong yeah but the nth central moment not just the nth moment, and then simplify expression?

Comment: @AlexanderMills I see. Then it's a matter of applying binomial theorem.

Comment: @Zhanxiong yeah, can you spell that out in an answer?

Comment: @AlexanderMills Can you post what you have tried and pointed out where the difficulty lies in deriving the final answer?

Comment: For a direct formula, see the Properties section of the Exponential distribution page on Wikipedia, $\mu_n=...$

Comment: an answer was added looks interesting

Answer (score 3):

Generally, when $X$ is *any* random variable with a defined positive integral moment $\mu_n(X) = E[X^n],$ then (a) $\mu_1 = \mu = E[X]$ is defined and (b) its *central* moment of order $n$ is given by the Binomial Theorem as a linear combination of moments

> $$\mu^\prime_n(X) = E[(X - \mu)^n] = E\left[\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}\mu^{n-i}X^i \right] = \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}\mu^{n-i}\mu_i(X).$$

This formula can be inverted to express moments in terms of central moments, too.  See Stuart & Ord, *Kendall's Advanced Theory of Statistics,* Volume 1.

---

Perhaps the easiest way to obtain the moments of an exponential random variable is through its moment generating function (mgf), here computed for a standard exponential distribution with density function $f_X = e^{-x}$ defined on the positive real numbers:

$$\begin{aligned}
\phi_X(t) &=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^i\mu_i\,t^i}{i!} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{-(1)^iE[X^i]\,t^i}{i!} = E\left[\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{(-tX)^i}{i!}\right]
= E\left[e^{-tX}\right]\\& = \int_0^\infty e^{-tx} e^{-x}\,\mathrm d x = \int_0^\infty e^{-(t+1)x}\,\mathrm dx = \frac{1}{-(t+1)}e^{-(t+1)x}\bigg|_0^\infty = (1+t)^{-1}\\
&= \sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^i t^i.
\end{aligned}$$

The first line is the entire point of the mgf, the second line is the elementary calculation of the integral, and the last line applies the Binomial Theorem.

Comparing these absolutely convergent power series term by term gives

$$\mu_i = i!.$$

When $\lambda$ is a rate parameter, $1/\lambda$ is a scale parameter.  The units calculus tells us to multiply $\mu_i$ by $(1/\lambda)^i$ in this case, producing the formula $\mu_i = i!/\lambda^i$ quoted in the question.  You may plug this in for $\mu_i$ in the general formula for central moments, bearing in mind $\mu = \mu_1 = 1/\lambda.$

Comment: well that looks nice

Comment: alright so for moment about the origin, for exponential it's `n!/^n`, I can't really tell what the answer is for central moments (about the mean)? In other words, I can't really tell what the answer is